# For iPhone 15 pro, set the default zoom for the camera to be 0.5x instead of 1x?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, camera, zoom

How do I set the default zoom for the camera to be 0.5x instead of 1x?

I have already turned on the setting for "Remember my last setting that I left the Camera app on". However, when I come back to the camera app, it opens again at 1x zoom. Please help!

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do this. The "Remember last setting ..." sets only the type of photo (video, photo, portrait, etc) not the settings within each type.

Comment: Correct @IconDaemon only a third party app can do this on iOS 17 at present. I'm hoping there's some developer that makes a shortcut to do this like they are enabling [other non-default actions for the action button on the new phones](https://daringfireball.net/linked/2023/09/22/current-action-button-shortcut) which replace the silent switch.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 17.0.2 there's no built in setting to default to wide angle photos. I don't see it as an option in the shortcuts app either, but perhaps someone can [make a custom app that works with shortcuts](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/actions/id1586435171) similar to the one linked here (which does other tasks - not camera ones) to call the specific API that apple provides develiopers to select the back camera, choose ultra wide, choose photo and then perform the capture, all in software.

```
AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .photo, position: .back)
```

I'm not aware of such an app, but will edit this if I find one. You will need Apple to change their software (make this a default, make a pre-shipped shortcut option in Photos to select wide angle) or [a developer to ship code as a shortcut automation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/choosing_a_capture_device) (or use another camera app entirely) for this to happen.

Comment: Cool thank you!